# Wrongly Styled React Toast

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

[image]Im getting wrong styling for React Toast. Close button is too big, how do i customize it?
Here is my Code signup.js
Link for the Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-keldysh-ukogpn?file=/src/signup.js

```
import  Axios  from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

import './main.css'

toast.configure()
export default function Signup() {

        const [name, setname] = useState('')
        const [email, setemail] = useState('')
        const [password, setpassword] = useState('')
        const [mobilenumber, setmobilenumber] = useState('')
        const [address, setaddress] = useState('')


    const togglepwdvis=(e)=>{
        let x=document.getElementById('pwdfield');
        if(x.type==='password')
        {
            x.type='text';
        }
        else
        {
            x.type='password';
        }
    }

    const handleregister=(e)=>{
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/registeruser',{
            name:name,
            email:email,
            password:password,
            mobilenumber:mobilenumber,
            address:address
        }).then(
            
            toast.success('Registered Successfully')
            
           
        )
        e.preventDefault();


    }

  return (
    <>

         <div class="page-wrapper bg-gra-01 p-t-170 p-b-80 font-poppins"   >
             <div></div><br />
        <div class="wrapper  wrapper--w960 "  style={{marginLeft:'240px'}} >
            <div class="card card-3" style={{width:'1000px'}}>
                <div class="card-heading"></div>
                <div class="card-body text-center" style={{width:'500px'}}  >
                    <h2 class="title">Registration </h2>
                    <form method="POST"  >
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="input--style-3" type="text" onChange={e=>setname(e.target.value)} placeholder="Name" name="username" required />
                        </div>
                        
                        
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="input--style-3" type="email" onChange={e=>setemail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Email" name="email"  required />
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group" style={{display:'flex',alignItems:'center'}}>
                            <input class="input--style-3" id='pwdfield' onChange={e=>setpassword(e.target.value)}  type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"  required />
                            
                            <a onClick={togglepwdvis}>
                            <span style={{color:'white',float: 'right',marginLeft: '-25px',marginTop: '0px',position: 'relative',zIndex:'  2'}}
                             toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>

                            </a>
                            
                        </div>


                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="input--style-3" type="text" onChange={e=>setmobilenumber(e.target.value)}  placeholder="Mobile Number" name="mobilenumber"  required />
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="input--style-3 js-datepicker" onChange={e=>setaddress(e.target.value)}  type="text" placeholder="Address" name="address"  required />
                           
                        </div>

                        <div class="p-t-10 text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn--pill btn--green" onClick={handleregister} type="submit">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </>
  )
}
```

Basically I show a toast when user registers successfully. But the Toast is just horrible.
My Code for App.js

```
[![import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Homegif from './components/Homegif';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,

  Route,Routes
} from "react-router-dom";
import Signup from './components/Signup';
import Login from './components/Login';
import About from './components/About';

import { toast, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

toast.configure();
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    
    <Router>
    <Navbar/>
    {/* <ToastContainer/> */}
    <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Homegif/>}>
              
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/" element={<About/>}>
              
          </Route>



          <Route exact path="/signup" element={<Signup/>}>
          
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>}>
            
          </Route>
      </Routes>




  
    </Router>
    
    </>
   
  );
}

export default App;][1]][1]
```

This is my code, where am i going wrong? IM writing this line only because of the warning stackoverflow gives me lol.

Comment: you can use mui icon close button. or try to use mui premaid dialog box or model box.

Comment: may be you can inspect the element to find the classname and then add custom css to that class, you should put the code in codesandbox and add the link to question so that we can help further

Comment: I did, please check it out once